# How to capitalize specific letters in a string given certain rules

Tags: python, string

I am massaging strings so that the 1st letter of the string and the first letter following either a dash or a slash needs to be capitalized.

So the following string:

test/string - this is a test string

Should look look like so:

Test/String - This is a test string

So in trying to solve this problem my 1st idea seems like a bad idea - iterate the string and check every character and using indexing etc. determine if a character follows a dash or slash, if it does set it to upper and write out to my new string.

```
def correct_sentence_case(test_phrase):

corrected_test_phrase = ''

firstLetter = True

for char in test_phrase:

    if firstLetter:

        corrected_test_phrase += char.upper()

        firstLetter = False

    #elif char == '/':
    else:

        corrected_test_phrase += char
```

This just seems VERY un-pythonic. What is a pythonic way to handle this?

Something along the lines of the following would be awesome but I can't pass in both a dash and a slash to the split:

```
corrected_test_phrase = ' - '.join(i.capitalize() for i in test_phrase.split(' - '))
```

Which I got from this SO:

[Convert UPPERCASE string to sentence case in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969202/convert-uppercase-string-to-sentence-case-in-python)

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Why doesn't your "wanted way" work? Split, capitalize and join

Comment: @SimonF Because it doesn't produce `Test/String - This is a test string` but `Test/string - This is a test string`

Comment: @SimonF - It works super nicely but I can't pass both dashes and slashes to the split - I probably should have said that in my question - it is unclear - ty

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.; do it in more than one step.

Comment: You have two different criteria for splitting. The one delimiter is `" - "` and the other is `"\"`. Do your split/capitalize in 2 passes. Split first on `" - "` into a list and then split every element of that list on `"\"`.

Comment: Pedro Rodrigues and BoarGules - TY for your comments and I agree completely - I tend to over-complicate things...

Comment: @beginAgain You were not unclear about what you wanted, only how you had tried to adapt the solution you found to your problem. The code you provided was only a loop away from working with all types of split-combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to accomplish the desired transformation with a regular expression:

```
import re
capitalized = re.sub(
    '(^|[-/])\s*([A-Za-z])', lambda match: match[0].upper(), phrase)
```

The expression says "anywhere you match either the start of the string, `^`, or a dash or slash followed by maybe some space and a word character, replace the word character with its uppercase."

[demo](https://repl.it/repls/VainBetterBetatest)

Comment: 7 seconds ahead of me, nice. Just be wary with using `\w` as it matches any of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (In a second thought it doesn't really  matter in this particular case)

Comment: Haha I noticed that. Very astute of you, I'll make the tweak

Comment: Wow - just tested and it works. Why do I always make stuff more complicated than it needs to be - ty :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go with a messy splitting-joining logic, go with a regex:

```
import re

string = 'test/string - this is a test string'

print(re.sub(r'(^([a-z])|(?<=[-/])\s?([a-z]))',
             lambda match: match.group(1).upper(), string))
# Test/String - This is a test string
```

Answer (score 2):

Using double split

```
import re
' - '.join([i.strip().capitalize() for i in re.split(' - ','/'.join([i.capitalize() for i in re.split('/',test_phrase)]))])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using that:

```
import string

last = 'pierre-GARCIA'

if last not in [None, '']:
    last = last.strip()
    if '-' in last:
        last = string.capwords(last, sep='-')
    else:
        last = string.capwords(last, sep=None)
```